# How CDN path will work in VS Code for Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cdn

[HTML FILE in which i put React CDN path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJ3JQ.jpg)[JS File which i code for React](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnRdE.jpg) The problem is that i am not getting any output while doing this, what is wrong here please tell, i am learning from Freecodecamp youtube react beginners tutorial

I want the text to be displayed in my HTML file through React js which didn't run through

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying upon cdn links I would heavily encourage you to use react locally.

Make sure nodejs and npm are installed in your machine and then execute this command

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

After this you are free to write any component and use. React by default provides boilerplate which you can use or delete